# Icon for contacts when contact is used by people app

Tags: android

I have tried a lot to add icon in connections of contacts of android phone whne that contact is used by my app.But I not able to get even a single reference to do it.Please do the favourable.I tried to use [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SocialStreamAcctType)

But not get any solution as its not properly explained.Simply I have to add icon like whats app goggle plus in phone contact if its used by my app

Answer (score 0):

This code works pretty well to get a photo, if I understand you correctly:

```
 Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
 InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, my_contact_Uri, true);
 BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
 Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
 buf.close();
 return my_btmp;
```

Look at this question: [Get high-res contact photo as bitmap below API level 14 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671814/get-high-res-contact-photo-as-bitmap-below-api-level-14-android) for more info.

Comment: Its not the what I want.I got solution for it.E.g firstly create account using accountManager after that you are able to sync. contacts with your app having registered account